# When can the eigenvalues be constrained to the right half plane as a result of column permutations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a real square matrix. Under what conditions is it possible to permute the columns of the matrix such that all eigenvalues of the resulting matrix have nonnegative real part?